# Как просмотреть только коммиты мастер ветки

Tags: git

Есть какой-то open-source проект где множество комитов, с системой подливания через `pull-request`.

Как из консоли просмотреть комиты только из мастер ветки?

По умолчанию команда `git log --oneline` выдаст мне все комиты по времени их создания. Тоесть будут видны комиты создаваемые в пулреквесте, но мне нужно увидить граф из пулреквестов, что бы проще было переключаться между ними для поиска баги.

`grep` по тексту коммитов `merge pull request`, или фильтр только мердж комитов неподходит, так как не очень редко в мастер добавляют просто коммиты от владельца репозитория

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно посмотреть:

```
git log --oneline --first-parent
```

Answer (score 3):

В гите не существует такого понятия как "коммиты только из мастер-ветки". В коммитах не хранится информация о ветке.

Можно было бы идти всегда по первому родителю для каждого слияния (и многие утилиты именно так и строят "мастер-ветку") - но эта эвристика часто ломается.

Answer (score 1):

Меня всегда спасал вот такой alias git'a:

```
[alias]
        tree        = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

Положите его в файл `~/.gitconfig`

Использую так:

```
$ git tree
* 506b39f (HEAD -> test) second at branch
* 07c0503 first at branch
* f00cb21 first
```

Если я хочу посмотреть все коммиты, которые были сделаны в моей ветке, начиная с точки, когда я отпочковался от `master` я выполняю:

```
git tree master..HEAD
* 506b39f (HEAD -> test) second at branch
* 07c0503 first at branch
```

тут мы видем только 2 коммита, которые были сделаны в ветке `test` и не видем коммитов, которые былы сделаны в ветке `master`

Если вы находитесь в ветке `test` и хотите посмотреть то, что изменилось в `master` с того времени как вы начали разработку, то выполните (три точки!!):

```
$ git diff test...master
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 8a1218a..eb095b3 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-1
-2
+11
+22
 3
 4
 5
```

И эти изменения были внесены коммитами (две точки!!):

```
$ git tree test..master
* 565b82a (master) thirt at master
* 1e408a9 second at master
```

Изменения в этих 2х коммитах:

```
$ git show 565b82a
commit 565b82a6319eb1afa5258bed37b640ec9a782679
Author: Eugen Konkov 
Date:   Mon Oct 24 20:36:39 2016 +0300

    thirt at master

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index bcba89f..eb095b3 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 11
-2
+22
 3
 4
 5
$ git show 1e408a9
commit 1e408a975a52fe9f6c32bd6cd7916c4ac082fd85
Author: Eugen Konkov
Date:   Mon Oct 24 20:36:27 2016 +0300

    second at master

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 8a1218a..bcba89f 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-1
+11
 2
 3
 4
```

И, аналогично, все изменения которые вы сделали в вашей ветке `test`, когда её отпочковали от `master`:

```
$ git diff master...test
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 8a1218a..ec28619 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 1
 2
 3
-4
-5
+45
+56
```

или если вы уже на ветке `test`, тогда можно писать `HEAD`:

```
$ git diff master...HEAD
```

Comment: Почти такой же использую. Про три точки интересно, не знал, спасибо.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: может я уже это показывал где-то. Вот [тут](https://geekbrains.ru/events/218) можно посмотреть про ещё более интересные настройки. Посмотреть конец начиная где-то с 1час 28мин. Если заинтересует, то можно всё глянуть.